# Algorithm or SQL : to find where conditions for a set of columns which ensures result set has value in a particular column always > 0

Tags: java, sql, oracle, algorithm, plsql

I am working on a java-oracle based project where I stuck with an problem which seems to me requires an analytic solution.
I am looking for solution either based on SQL query or any algorithm or any free analytic tool which I can follow to get desired results.

**Problem statement:**
Lets us say I have below table with columnA-D and last column as Score, I want to find an criteria on values for each of the columns which when combined in SQL where clause will always give me positive value for Score column. So basically what combination of columnA-D will always give me positive score?

```html
columnA|columnB|columnC|columnD|Score
  1      40      10       3     -20
  0      40      2        3      10
  0      10      3        3      20
  1      15      3        3     -5
  0      10      2        2     -15
  0      15      6        3     -10
```

**Expected result for above data set:-**
Visual interpretation of above data set gives me condition: *“ColumnA =0 and columnB >10 and columnC  <5 will ensure score always >0”. (visually its clear columnD does not have an effect).*

*Please note above data set is for sake of simplicity. In reality, my project contains around 40 columns with almost 2500 rows. One thing is for sure each of columns have finite range of values.*

---

### Following information copied from OPs answer below

Here is an algorithm I started with (need inputs to refine it further if someone thinks I am in right direction):

Preparation: Create an list of all possible expressions like A=0, B>10,C<5 (for 40 columns, I finalized total approx 150 expressions)

Let us call it "expressions" variable.

Alogrithm for 1st run:

1. set totalPositiveRows= select count(*) from my tables where score>0;

   set totalNegativeRows= select count(*) from my tables where score<0;
2. For each expr in expressions, calculate following three variables
       set positivePercentage= find percentage of totalPositiveRows which satisfy this expr; //like if 60 rows out of total 100 rows  having score>0 satisfy expr , then positivePercentage=60%

   ```
   set negativePercentage= find percentage of totalNegativeRows which satisfy this expr; //like if 40 rows out of total 100 rows  having score<0 satisfy expr , then negativePercentage=40%

   set diffPercentage=positivePercentage-negativePercentage;
   ```
3. Set initialexpr=Choose expr having maximum value of diffPercentage
   set initalPositivePercentage=choose corresponding positivePercentage value; 
   set initalNegativePercentage=choose corresponding negativePercentage value;
   My thinking is that I need to now keep expanding initalexpr until initalNegativePercentage becomes 0.

Alogrithm for subsequent runs until initalNegativePercentage becomes 0:-

1. For each expr in expressions, calculate following three variables
   set newexpr=initialexpr+" and "+expr;
   set positivePercentage= find percentage of totalPositiveRows which satisfy newexpr;
   set negativePercentage= find percentage of totalNegativeRows which satisfy  newexpr;

   //calculate how much negative percentage it has reduced?
   set positiveReduction=initalPositivePercentage-positivePercentage;
   set negativeReduction=initalNegativePercentage-negativePercentage;
   if(negativeReduction>=positiveReduction)
   //note it down
   else
   //discard it
2. Choose the expr which gives maxium negative reduction, that becomes new inital expr.
   Set initialexpr=Choose expr having maximum value of negativeReduction
   set initalPositivePercentage=choose corresponding value; 
   set initalNegativePercentage=choose corresponding value;
3. Repeat the algorithm above.

Please comment.

Comment: What does the 2500 other rows says about your "expected result for above data set"? Is your statement true for that as well?

Comment: @PresidentCamacho , yes positive score is logical representation of all columns and it holds true for all 2500 rows. I know there should be feasible solution, I just don't know how to get it.

Comment: Use **CASE** construct, see my answer.

Comment: I think we need more background information. For me `score` sounds like something that is calculated from `colA...` before every value is inserted into the db and this calculation happens somewhere "outside"? Why can't you use that outside calculation to examine the problem?

Comment: @OcasoProtal, no I can confirm score is not derived from any of the column values.

Comment: Ahh, now I understand. Score is not derived but you want "some kind of derivation" for the current set of records. So when a new line is added you have to recalculate that derivation.

Comment: A trivial solution is to pick any row with positive score, and then form the expression by requiring that columns have values equal to their values in that row (e.g. `A=0, B=50, C=1, D=3`).  If that isn't what you want, then maybe what you want is the expression that returns the *largest possible* set of rows.  But then I'm pretty sure that there are multiple different expressions that could do that, due to interactions.

Comment: Why are you doing this?  Do you need to find such an expression satisfying *all* rows with a positive score, or does an approximation algorithm suffice?

Comment: we have a business decision aligned to it ....it kind of provide analytic insight to us....so we are trying to find expression satisfying all rows with positive score..

Comment: Is it true that the columns are **independent** so the optimal solution for one column does not affect other columns? Are you trying to find some kind of causality in your data? It looks like some machine learning problem.

Comment: @ibre5041, please go through one algorithm I submitted below...that may clarify my problem further...

Comment: can you give some background information for what pupose

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Below is a brute-force solution.  This might also be a good question for the theoretical computer science site.  I *think* this is an NP-complete problem similar to [Boolean satisfiability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_satisfiability_problem), but that's just a wild guess.  There may be a smarter way to solve this but I don't think I'll find it.

The basic idea is to cross join every expression with every distinct value for a column, and then cross join all the columns.  The table will be queried with every expression list, and a count generated for positive and negative scores.  If the expression returns the expected number of positive scores and none of the negative scores it is valid.

This assumes that you are only using the expressions `>`, `<`, and `=`.  Every new column or expression will make this problem exponentially slower.

**Test schema**

```
drop table table1;
create table table1(a number, b number, c number, d number, score number);

insert into table1
select  1,      40,      10,       3,     -20 from dual union all
select  0,      40,      2,        3,      10 from dual union all
select  0,      10,      3,        3,      20 from dual union all
select  1,      15,      3,        3,     -5  from dual union all
select  0,      10,      2,        2,     -15 from dual union all
select  0,      15,      6,        3,     -10 from dual;
```

**Wall of code**

```
declare
    v_inline_view varchar2(32767);
    v_inline_views clob;
    v_inline_view_counter number := 0;
    v_and_expression varchar2(32767);
    v_query clob;

    v_sqls sys.odcivarchar2list;
    v_dynamic_query_counter number := 0;
begin
    --#1: Create inline views.
    --One for every combination of expression and distinct value, per column.
    for inline_views in
    (
        --Inline view for every possible expression for each column.
        select
            replace(q'[
            (
                select *
                from
                (
                    --Possible expressions.
                    select distinct
                        case
                            when operator is null then null
                            else ' AND %%COLUMN%% '||operator||' '||%%COLUMN%%
                        end %%COLUMN%%_expression
                    from
                    --All operators.
                    (
                        select '>'  operator from dual union all
                        select '<'  operator from dual union all
                        select '='  operator from dual union all
                        select null operator from dual
                    )
                    --All distinct values.
                    cross join
                    (
                        select distinct %%COLUMN%% from table1
                    )
                )
                --where %%COLUMN%%_expression is null or %%COLUMN%%_expression %%EXPRESSION_PERFORMANCE_EXCLUSIONS%%
            )
            ]', '%%COLUMN%%', column_name) inline_view
        from user_tab_columns
        where table_name = 'TABLE1'
            and column_name <> 'SCORE'
        order by column_name
    ) loop
        --Assign to temorary so it can be modified.
        v_inline_view := inline_views.inline_view;

        --#1A: Optimize inline view - throw out expressions if they don't return any positive results.
        declare
            v_expressions sys.odcivarchar2list;
            v_expressions_to_ignore varchar2(32767);
            v_has_score_gt_0 number;
        begin
            --Gather expressions for one column.
            execute immediate v_inline_view bulk collect into v_expressions;

            --Loop through and test each expression.
            for i in 1 .. v_expressions.count loop
                --Always keep the null expression.
                if v_expressions(i) is not null then
                    --Count the number of rows with a positive score.
                    execute immediate 'select nvl(max(case when score > 0 then 1 else 0 end), 0) from table1 where '||replace(v_expressions(i), ' AND ', null)
                    into v_has_score_gt_0;

                    --If the expression returns nothing positive then add it to exclusion.
                    if v_has_score_gt_0 = 0 then
                        v_expressions_to_ignore := v_expressions_to_ignore||','''||v_expressions(i)||'''';
                    end if;
                end if;
            end loop;

            --Convert it into an IN clause.
            if v_expressions_to_ignore is not null then
                --Remove comment, replace placeholder with expression exclusions.
                v_inline_view := regexp_replace(v_inline_view, '(.*)(--where)( .* )(%%EXPRESSION_PERFORMANCE_EXCLUSIONS%%)(.*)', '\1where\3 not in ('||substr(v_expressions_to_ignore, 2)||')');
            end if;
        end;

        --Aggregate and count inline views.
        if v_inline_view_counter <> 0 then
            v_inline_views := v_inline_views||'cross join';
        end if;

        v_inline_views := v_inline_views||v_inline_view;

        v_inline_view_counter := v_inline_view_counter + 1;
    end loop;

    --#2: Create an AND expression to combine all column expressions.
    select listagg(column_name||'_expression', '||') within group (order by column_name)
    into v_and_expression
    from user_tab_columns
    where table_name = 'TABLE1'
        and column_name <> 'SCORE';


    --#3: Create a that will create all possible expression combinations.
    v_query := 
    replace(replace(q'[
        --8281 combinations
        select '
            select
                '''||expressions||''' expression,
                nvl(sum(case when score > 0 then 1 else 0 end), 0) gt_0_score_count,
                nvl(sum(case when score <= 0 then 1 else 0 end), 0) le_0_score_count
            from table1
            where 1=1 '||expressions v_sql
        from
        (
            --Combine expressions
            select %%AND_EXPRESSION%% expressions
            from
            %%INLINE_VIEWS%%
        ) combined_expressions
    ]', '%%AND_EXPRESSION%%', v_and_expression), '%%INLINE_VIEWS%%', v_inline_views);

    --TEST: It might be useful to see the full query here.
    --dbms_output.put_line(v_query);

    --#4: Gather expressions.
    --With larger input you'll want to use a LIMIT
    execute immediate v_query
    bulk collect into v_sqls;

    --#5: Test each expression.  
    --Look for any queries that return the right number of rows.
    for i in 1 .. v_sqls.count loop
        declare
            v_expression varchar2(4000);
            v_gt_0_score_count number;
            v_le_0_score_count number;
        begin
            execute immediate v_sqls(i) into v_expression, v_gt_0_score_count, v_le_0_score_count;
            v_dynamic_query_counter := v_dynamic_query_counter + 1;

            --TODO: Dynamically generate "2".
            if v_gt_0_score_count = 2 and v_le_0_score_count = 0 then
                dbms_output.put_line('Expression: '||v_expression);
            end if;

        exception when others then
            dbms_output.put_line('Problem with: '||v_sqls(i));
        end;
    end loop;

    dbms_output.put_line('Queries executed: '||v_dynamic_query_counter);

end;
/
```

**Results**

The results appear correct.  They are slightly different than yours because "columnB > 10" is incorrect.

```
Expression:  AND A = 0 AND C < 6 AND D = 3
Expression:  AND A = 0 AND C < 6 AND D > 2
Expression:  AND A < 1 AND C < 6 AND D = 3
Expression:  AND A < 1 AND C < 6 AND D > 2
Queries executed: 441
```

**Problems**

This brute-force approach is extremely inefficient in at least two ways.  Even for this simple example it requires 6370 queries..  And the results may include duplicates that are non-trivial to reduce.  Or perhaps you'll get lucky and there are so few solutions that you can eyeball them.

There are a few things you can do to improve query performance.  The easiest one would be to check every condition individually and throw it out if it does not "gain" anything for the counts.

**Optimizations**

Individual expressions that do not return any positive results are excluded.  With the sample data, this reduces the number of query executions from 6370 to 441.

Running the process in parallel may also improve the performance by an order of magnitude.  It would probably require a parallel pipelined function.

But even a 100x performance improvement may not help with an NP-complete problem.  You may need to find some additional "short cuts" based on your sample data.

It may help to print out the query that generates the test queries, by un-commenting one of the `dbms_output.put_line` statements.  Add a `count(*)` to see how many queries will be executed and run with a smaller data set to make an estimate for how long it will take.

If the estimate is a billion years, and you can't think of any tricks to make the brute-force method work faster, it may be time to ask this question on https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks Jon Heller. This seems a good one, I need to try out this concept on my larger data set...will update you.

Comment: my system just hang when I tried for 20 columns for large data set...as you expected the time taken increase exponentially....

Comment: thanks for your efforts made...I almost spent 2 full days to making your logic working on my data set..the results futile unfortunately.....i have opened up a bounty expecting more algorithms for above problem else I suppose I need to publish it in cstheory.

Comment: could you please check algorithm I have published and provide your inputs what do you think?

Comment: @ag112 I'm having a difficult time understanding all these algorithms.  Could you expand on the example with more rows and columns, and fix the "columnB > 10" issue?  I think I may have a better way to do this, but I'd need more data to test if it's more efficient.

Comment: I have corrected data set to fix column B> 10 issue.

Comment: @ag112 The new data is still not sufficient to test for optimizations.  If you could double or triple the number of rows, with real data, it might be enough to tell if a solution is feasible for 40 columns and 2500 rows.  Or, if it's not proprietary, maybe you could post a link to the full data set.

Comment: thanks. sure let me arrange more data set and update the question.

Comment: I found your solution more relevant and provide more closer results to my data set

Answer (score 2):

The idea of the solution is that the columns are **independent**. So it can be solved column by column.

So you can imagine that you search and build something in multidimensional space. Each column represents a dimension, having values from `-inf` to `+inf`. And build the solution dimension by dimension.

- For the 1st column the solution is: `A=1 => false, A=0 => true.`
- Then you add 2nd dimension B. You have 5 values, so dimension on column B be is divided into 6 intervals. Some of the consecutive intervals can be joined. For example <10, 50> and <50,inf> do both imply true.
- And then you add 3rd dimension.
- ...

If you want to join dimension intervals on SQL level you can use LAG function. By using partitioning and windowing you order rows by one column. Then you compute a value true/false in a cooked column. And in the next cooked column by using the LAG function you detect whether the true/false flag did change from the previous row.

```
create table test
(
  b number,
  s number
);

insert into test values(10, -20);
insert into test values(50,  10);
insert into test values(15,  20);
insert into test values(18,  5);

select u.*,
 case when LAG (b, 1, null) OVER (ORDER BY b) = b then 'Y' else 'N' end same_b_value,
 LAG (score_flag, 1, null) OVER (ORDER BY b) AS score_flag_prev,
 case when LAG (score_flag, 1, null) OVER (ORDER BY b) <> score_flag then 'Y' else 'N' end score_flag_changed
from
(
  select t.*,
  case when t.s >= 0 then 'Y' else 'N' end as score_flag
  from test t
)  u
order by b asc;
```

This query will show that value `B=15` is significant because it is where the score_flag changes.

I'm not sure about value `B=10` in the question. As this one is linked to both positive and negative score values. Should it be included or excluded then?

Comment: thanks. Could you please expand your code with more columns and join among them. I really could not figure it out myself..........

Answer (score 1):

Very interesting problem. My proposition bases on function check_column, code below. Execution examples:

```
select CHECK_COLUMN('col01') from dual;    => "COL01 = 0"
select CHECK_COLUMN('col03') from dual;    => "COL03 <= 2"

select column_name cn, check_column(column_name) crit 
  from all_tab_columns atc      
  where atc.table_name='SCORES' and column_name like 'COL%';

cn          crit
COL01       COL01 = 0
COL02       COL02 >= 32  
COL03       COL03 <= 2
COL04       COL04 = COL04
```

In your example, row 3, columnB I replaced value 10 with 32, because example was not good, and condition *and columnB >10* was not right. Col04 is only for presentation, as it's neutral. You need to stick output strings together in java or sql, but that shouldn't be a problem.

I named base table as `scores`, then created view `positives`, you can instead of view put data in some temporary table, execution should be much faster.

```
create or replace view positives as
  select distinct col01, col02, col03, col04 
    from scores where score>0
  minus select COL01,COL02,COL03,COL04
    from scores where score<0;
```

Function is:

```
create or replace function check_column(i_col in varchar2) return varchar2 as
  v_tmp number;
  v_cnt number;
  v_ret varchar2(4000);
begin
  -- candidate for neutral column ?
  execute immediate 'select count(distinct '||i_col||') from positives' into v_tmp;
  execute immediate 'select count(distinct '||i_col||') from scores' into v_cnt;
  if v_tmp = v_cnt then
    return i_col||' = '||i_col;   -- empty string is better, this is for presentation 
  end if;

  -- candidate for "column = some_value" ?
  execute immediate 'select count(distinct '||i_col||') from positives' into v_cnt;
  if v_cnt = 1 then
    execute immediate 'select distinct '||i_col||' from positives' into v_tmp;
    return i_col||' = '||v_tmp; 
  end if;

  -- is this candidate for "column >= some_value" ?
  execute immediate 'select min(distinct '||i_col||') from positives' into v_tmp;
  execute immediate 'select count(1) from scores where '||i_col||
    ' not in (select '||i_col||' from positives) and '||i_col||'>'||v_tmp into v_cnt;
  if v_cnt = 0 then
    execute immediate 'select min('||i_col||') from scores' into v_cnt;
    if v_cnt != v_tmp then 
      return i_col||' >= '||v_tmp; 
    end if;
  end if;

  -- is this candidate for "column <= some_value" ?
  execute immediate 'select max(distinct '||i_col||') from positives' into v_tmp;
  execute immediate 'select count(1) from scores where '||i_col||
    ' not in (select '||i_col||' from positives) and '||i_col||'<'||v_tmp into v_cnt;
  if v_cnt = 0 then 
    execute immediate 'select max('||i_col||') from scores' into v_cnt;
    if v_cnt != v_tmp then
      return i_col||' <= '||v_tmp;
    end if;
  end if;

  -- none of the above, have to list specific values
  execute immediate 'select listagg('||i_col||', '', '') '
    ||'within group (order by '||i_col||') '
    ||'from (select distinct '||i_col||' from positives)' into v_ret;
  return i_col||' in ('||v_ret||')';
end check_column;
```

This solution is nor optimized nor heavily tested, please be careful.
If you have Oracle version < 11 replace listagg with wmsys.wm_concat.

Comment: it is taking bit time for me to understand your logic:)

Comment: I think your logic will not work because your logic relies on positives view where as I expect logic should consider negatives. For e.g. your first candidate condition for "column = some_value" , let us say I have a column whose value is 5 for all rows (positive and negative score), then i don't want this column to be considered in where condition but your logic will take it up.

Comment: Changed order of steps in function. Modified view `positives` to eliminate scenario (15, 5, 7, 2, -1)  (15, 5, 7, 2, 1). If view is empty then output condition cannot be built.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I would do:

1. Check the minimum and maximum values for every "input" column
2. Check the minimum and maximum values for every "input" column for the subset where score > 0

Now, for each "input" column:

3. If the minimum and maximum values for point 1 and point 2 are the same, that column has no bearing
4. Otherwise, if the minimum and maximum values for point 2 are the same, that column is an "="
5. Otherwise, if the minimum is the same but the maximum is not, that column is a "<" with the maximum from point 2 as the reference
6. Otherwise, if the maximum is the same but the minimum is not, that column is a ">" with the minimum from point 2 as the reference
7. Otherwise, the column is a "< AND >"

Note that this all assumes that Score is (hypothetically) driven by *continuous ranges* in the "input" columns. It won't be able to spot conditions of, say "<5 or >10", or "<>12". Since neither of those are not in your example, I speculate it might be fine, but if it's not, you're back to NP-complete...

SQL to generate queries to output the conditions above for an arbitrary schema should be relatively easy to construct. Let me know if you want a hand with that and I'll look into it.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT min(a), max(a) from MyTable WHERE score > 0;
SELECT min(a), max(a) from MyTable;

SELECT min(b), max(b) from MyTable WHERE score > 0;
SELECT min(b), max(b) from MyTable;

SELECT min(c), max(c) from MyTable WHERE score > 0;
SELECT min(c), max(c) from MyTable;

SELECT min(d), max(d) from MyTable WHERE score > 0;    
SELECT min(d), max(d) from MyTable;
```

This will give you the range of each column for positive scores, then the range of these columns over all scores.  Where these ranges are different, you have a correlation

Comment: nope it does not work...there are many columns having binary data i.e. just 0 and 1...what min and max mean there?

Comment: It means exactly the same as any other column; if a column has a range of 0 - 1 and the score >0 range is also 0 to 1, then there is no correlation.  If a column has a range of 0 to 1, and the score > 0 range is 0 to 0 or 1 to 1, then you have a corellation.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an algorithm I started with (need inputs to refine it further if someone thinks I am in right direction):

**Preparation:**
Create an list of all possible expressions like A=0, B>10,C<5 (for 40 columns, I finalized total approx 150 expressions)

*Let us call it "expressions" variable.*

**Alogrithm for 1st run:**

```
1. set totalPositiveRows= select count(*) from my tables where score>0;

   set totalNegativeRows= select count(*) from my tables where score<0;

2.   For each expr in expressions, calculate following three variables
        set positivePercentage= find percentage of totalPositiveRows which satisfy this expr; //like if 60 rows out of total 100 rows  having score>0 satisfy expr , then positivePercentage=60%

        set negativePercentage= find percentage of totalNegativeRows which satisfy this expr; //like if 40 rows out of total 100 rows  having score<0 satisfy expr , then negativePercentage=40%

        set diffPercentage=positivePercentage-negativePercentage;

3. Set initialexpr=Choose expr having maximum value of diffPercentage
   set initalPositivePercentage=choose corresponding positivePercentage value; 
   set initalNegativePercentage=choose corresponding negativePercentage value;
```

My thinking is that I need to now keep expanding initalexpr  until initalNegativePercentage becomes 0.

**Alogrithm for subsequent runs until initalNegativePercentage becomes 0:-**

```
1. For each expr in expressions, calculate following three variables        
  set newexpr=initialexpr+" and "+expr;
  set positivePercentage= find percentage of totalPositiveRows which satisfy newexpr;
  set negativePercentage= find percentage of totalNegativeRows which satisfy  newexpr;

  //calculate how much negative percentage it has reduced?
  set positiveReduction=initalPositivePercentage-positivePercentage;
  set negativeReduction=initalNegativePercentage-negativePercentage;
  if(negativeReduction>=positiveReduction)
    //note it down
  else
    //discard it

2. Choose the expr which gives maxium negative reduction, that becomes new inital expr.
    Set initialexpr=Choose expr having maximum value of negativeReduction
   set initalPositivePercentage=choose corresponding value; 
   set initalNegativePercentage=choose corresponding value;

3. Repeat the algorithm above.
```

Please comment.

Comment: So you can imagine that you search and build something in multidimensional space. Each column represents a dimension. And build the solution dimension by dimension. For the 1st column the solution is: `A=1 => false, A=0 => true`. Then you add 2nd dimension `B`. You have 5 values, so dimension on column `B` be is divided into 6 intervals. Some of the consecutive intervals can be joined. For example `<10, 50> and <50,inf>` do both imply `true`. And then you add 3rd dimension.

Comment: PS: If you want to join dimension intervals on SQL level you can use `LAG` function. By using partitioning and windowing you order rows by one column. Then you compute a value true/false in a cooked column. And in the next cooked column by using the `LAG` function you detect whether the true/false flag did change from the previous row.

Comment: @ibre5041...sorry I am not from analytic area so really don't understand LAG function term etc....is it possible for you to give an working example? I am good in java and pl/sql .

Comment: See this fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/1891c/9. `select u.*,
 LAG (score_flag, 1, null) OVER (ORDER BY b) AS score_flag_prev,
 case when LAG (score_flag, 1, null) OVER (ORDER BY b) <> score_flag then 'Y' else 'N' end score_flag_changed
from
(
  select t.*,
  case when t.s >= 0 then 'Y' else 'N' end as score_flag
  from test t
)  u
order by b asc;` This query will order rows according to the column `B` and the column score_flag_changed will mark values in `B` which are significant to the row validity

Comment: @ibre5041, could you please elaborate it as separate answer to have more space for writing.....so in your example, score_flag_changed=Y for B=15, does that mean B=15 is one of candidate for chosen conditions?...how would you take this concept further to making "AND" between conditions?

Comment: Please don't submit answers to your own question that add information to the question. Instead, go back and edit the question to include the information. Using an answer to add information to the question just means that people may not find it. I did it for you this time, and as such you should really remove this answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple implementation that will result in a complicated set of rules.

Let A be the set of all inputs that result in a positive score, and B be the set of all inputs that don't result in a positive score.

If any set of inputs is in both A and B then no rule will give all the positives and no negatives. Regardless, A-B is a set of rules that will give only positive values, and no set of rules that excludes all non-positives can do better.

In your example, our rules are:
(colA=0, colB=40, colC=2, colD=3),
(colA=0, colB=10, colC=3, colD=3).

Comment: Once you have these rules, you can look for commonalities.